# Accessing text in html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access the string `Out of Stock` using BeautifulSoup but cannot find the way to it:

```
<span style="color: #727272; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">
    <strong>Price: $790</strong>
     (Out of stock)
</span>
```

Can anybody give hints how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.next_sibling` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the element after the `<strong>` tag:

```
span.strong.next_sibling
```

There is probably extra whitespace around that string, so you could use `str.strip()` to clean that up.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <span style="color: #727272; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;">
...     <strong>Price: $790</strong>
...      (Out of stock)
... </span>
... ''')
>>> soup.span.strong
<strong>Price: $790</strong>
>>> soup.span.strong.next_sibling
u'\n     (Out of stock)\n'
>>> soup.span.strong.next_sibling.strip()
u'(Out of stock)'
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't got to that part in tutorial but it just worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_text)
soup.get_text().split('\n')[2].strip()
```